# Why is the ratio of the slope of a line always equal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Imagine you have one triangle and the hypotenuse is a line $AB$.

Now the slope of this triangle is defined as:

$$ m =\frac{y_i-y_1}{x_i-x_1} $$

$i$ = any number on the line $AB$

Now instead if you were to take a few points on this line $AB$ and performed the operation:

$$ \frac{y_5}{x_5} =k_5, \frac{y_4}{x_4}=k_4, \frac{y_3}{x_3}=k_3....... $$

It turns out that

$$ k_5 =k_4 = k_3.......$$

Now my question is why is the ratio of the slope at every point on the line $AB$, equal?

Why does $k_5=k_4=k_3$ and so on

Comment: This is because of *Thales' theorem*.

Comment: It all form similar triangles. A line is also formed from a point by a constant slope

Comment: The above statement about constant $k_i$ is wrong, unless the line includes $(0,0)$.

Comment: I see, yes the line starts at (0,0)

Comment: If any of the answers below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) (if you can) all answers you find useful **and** [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

The equation of any line can be written in slope-point form.
$$y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$$
Leaving it in this form, we simply divide over the $(x-x_1)$
$$\frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1} = m$$ 
Holds true for any line. Because $(y_1, x_1)$ was any fixed point on the line, and $(x,y)$ is defined as a variable point, we can see this holds true for all points on the line.

Thus, there is always a constant ratio, $m$ for each pair of points on the line.

Comment: Thank you, yes I understand that. But I am asking what is the reason that this constant ratio is observed. Or is that simply how a line is defined as having a constant ratio

Answer (score 1):

I think the comment from N.S.John is particularly useful, so let me expand it a bit for you.  Suppose you compute the slope of $AB$ using two points on it, say $P$ and $Q$, so the slope you get is the quotient $y/x$ of the vertical distance $y$ by the horizontal distance $x$ between those points. Notice that these distances are the two sides of a right triangle whose hypotenuse is the segment $PQ$ of the line $AB$.  You get this triangle by drawing a horizontal line through $P$ and a vertical line through $Q$, and finding their intersection point, which I'll call $X$. The triangle is $PXQ$ and the slope you computed is the ratio of lengths $(XQ)/(XP)$.

Now suppose I come along and compute the slope of the same line $AB$ using two other points on it, say $P'$ and $Q'$.  As before, form a right triangle $P'X'Q'$, where the slope that I computed is the ratio of lengths $(X'Q')/(X'P')$. Your question is why my slope and your slope are the same.

The reason is that the triangles $PXQ$ and $P'X'Q'$ are similar.  The angles at $X$ and $X'$ are equal because they are both right angles.  The angles at $P$ and $P'$ are equal because they are corresponding angles where the parallel (horizontal) lines $PX$ and $P'X'$ are cut by the transversal $AB$.  Those equalities between angles imply similarity of the triangles.  And similarity implies, in turn, equality of ratios of corresponding sides --- which is exacly what you wanted.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. So basically all the triangles that I can cut from line AB will be similar to each other and thus have the same slope, because they have the same right angle and the same angle with the line AB.

Comment: @AndreasBlass -  I have a general question about the slope of a line: suppose that the slope of a line is $m = \frac{2}{3}$ (in units meters/seconds, for example), then is saying “the rate of change is two meters per three seconds“ equivalent to saying “the rate of change is two-thirds meters per second” by converting to a *unit rate*?

Comment: @TaylorRendon Yes, "two meters per three seconds" is the same as "$2/3$ meters per second" (provided of course that your speed is constant so the graph is a straight line).

Answer (score 0):

A line is defined by all the points $(x,y)$ of the plane verifying $ax+by+c=0$ for given $a,b,c$. So the slope of a line is always constant ($\frac{b}{a}$). I am guessing that in your case, you have $c=0$ (your line goes through $(0,0)$), so calculating $\frac{y_i}{x_i}$ is equivalent to calculating the slope (hence gives a constant ratio).

Comment: But why is the slope of a line that goes through the point (0,0) the same for every point. Like what is the reason, the fundamental property I guess

Comment: The slope of ANY line is ALWAYS the same. That is what defines lines.